# How do I "bake in" cross references?

Tags: cross-referencing

We've been writing a paper with its supplementary materials as two .tex files, using the `xr` package to handle cross-references. Now the journal wants the sources for just the paper, and I think this would require two files: the paper.tex and the supplemental.aux. Is there a way to provide the paper without needing the .aux file?

[This similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220744/14635) is unanswered, but a comment suggests including the .aux file directly in the .tex using `\begin{filecontents*}`.  That would probably work, but is there also a way to "bake-in" the references, i.e. replace all of the `\ref{foo}` in the .tex file with the corresponding values that are inserted upon typesetting?

Comment: This sounds like a scripting problem, not a TeX problem. TeX, for obvious reasons, doesn't usually (always?) modify `.tex` files. Other sites might be better place to answer how to take find/match line/snippet X in file Y and snippet A in file B and then replace A with Y.

Comment: If this is just a question of a journal wanting everything tied up for them in a single file with a pretty little bow on it, you can always make a separate file to send to them, inputting the contents of the `.aux` file in between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, with `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`.

Comment: If the journal is happy to accept a TeX file then they presumably know how to use TeX and so they can generate their own aux file. Given this I seriously doubt that they want the aux file as well. You might want to manually include your bbl files, which contain bibliographic information, but aux should be unnecessary.